# If $G$ is a group with order $99$, it is cyclic by Sylow (isn't it?). I want to find a generator.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have seen an argument in a specific case where $g,h\in G$ with $ord(g)=9$ and $ord(h)=11$ are used to create a generator through $f:=g^xh^y$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $1=x9+y11$.

Is this possible in general?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, it need not be cyclic. Consider $\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_{11}$, although if $9$ where prime it would definitely have to be cyclic by Sylow.

Also, "finding a generator of a group" is not a reasonable question when the group is defined up to isomorphism. This question makes sense when the isomorphism between a cyclic group and the group in question is not clear. For example when finding a generator for the multiplicative group $\bmod p$, which is known to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{p-1}$

Comment: Presumably by "it must not be cyclic", you mean "it need not be cyclic"?

Comment: yeah, or "it must not necessarily be cyclic" or something like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any n, upto isomorphism there exist a cyclic group of order n,namely$Z_n$.So for n=99 you definitely have a cyclic group of order 99,namely $Z_{99}$which is generated by 1.But as mentioned in the earlier post upto isomorphism there could exist other groups of order 99.In that case you will not get "a generator" but generators as the group is finite.